# SafeMath Utility Error in Ethereum Document 'Unique Digital Asset' Code

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, safemath

I refer to the example code 'Unique Digital Asset' code in Ethereum Doc (https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/anatomy/#unique-digital-asset) line 60.

uint256 id = SafeMath.sub(pizzas.push(Pizza(_name, _dna)), 1);

While running this I am getting error: Member "sub" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library SafeMath). How to resolve this. I am using openzeppelin 3.0 and Solidity 0.8.0.

Comment: share your code if possible; it would seem that you are not importing the library...

Comment: I am importing the library as:                                                                                   
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol"; TypeError: Member "sub" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library SafeMath). This is directly copied from ethereum docs example but still I am  unable to run. I have already given the link above. Please give it a look.